# Why casting from a stack to int is not running in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to cast a char that is stored in stack to an integer and this is what I did.

```
operands = new StackLinked();

if ( (a == '0') || (a == '1') || (a == '2') || (a == '3') || (a == '4') || 
     (a == '5') || (a == '6') || (a == '7') || (a == '8') || (a == '9') )
{
   operands.push(a);   /*Stor operands in the stack operands.*/
}

//This line crushes my program. I don't know why.
int op1 = ((Integer)operands.peek()).intValue();
```

Comment: What do you mean 'crushes' you program?

Comment: By the way, put four spaces in front of your code so it gets formatted as such.

Comment: @stimms: I think she means 'crashes'. It probably throws an excception. I may help to know which one.

Comment: Whenever a Java application "crashes", there is usually a StackTrace. It is invaluable to understanding exactly what happened to cause the program to fail. Posting it here would help immensely.

Comment: @tweakt: Agreed. It would also be helpful to show the declaration of "operands" and "a", as well as telling us where StackLinked comes from (as it's not a standard class).

Answer (score 7):

You haven't shown the declaration for `a` but I suspect it's of type `char`. That's then autoboxed to `Character`, and so when you cast to `Integer` the cast fails.

If you change your code to use:

```
operands.push((int) a);
```

that should convert from `char` to `int` then box to `Integer` and you'll be away.

Alternatively, use:

```
// Implicit conversion from char to int
int op1 = ((Character) operands.peek()).charValue();
```

**EDIT:** Note that the above solutions would both end up giving op1=49 when a='1', op2=50 when a='2' etc. If you actually want op1=1 when a='1' you could either use `Character.digit` or (as we already know that 'a' is in the range '0' to '9') you could just subtract '0', i.e.

```
operands.push((int) (a-'0'));
```

or

```
int op1 = ((Character) operands.peek()).charValue() - '0';
```

In the first case the cast is actually then redundant, as the result of the subtraction will be `int` rather than `char` - but I'd leave it there for clarity.

Comment: The implicit conversion gives you a 1 for the character '1' or a 49 (ASCII code for '1')?

Comment: Yes, it does. This may or may not be the desired operation. We're not working with much information here :(

Comment: To clarify, the conversion of '1' results in the int value of 49.

Comment: I found a "warning" in one of Jon Skeet's answers! I rock!

Answer (score 1):

You must be using 1.5. So here's one more way to get it right:

```
if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') {
    operands.push(a);
}

char c = operands.peek();
int op1 = (int) c; //check Character.isDigit(c), if there is other stuff in the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to convert a char to an int value is to do

```
if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') {
    operands.push(a - '0'); // converts a char to an int.
}
int op1 = (Integer) operands.peek();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually pushing anything onto the stack?  If not then your casting line with throw EmptyStackException.  What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your example may be a little ambiguous, here are my assumptions:

- You are using Java 1.5 langauge features (due to boxing/unboxing).
- *operands* is behaving similar to Stack<Character>();

When you push a char into the stack, it's boxed as a Character. You can't cast Character instance to an Integer. You must use get the primitive numeric value, then cast it to an integer primitive.

Try this:

```
int op1 = (int) operands.peek().charValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard without seeing the definition of StackLinked, is that one of your own classes?

I can think of several options:
The stack is somehow empty (e.g., a was not one of these characters').

Or the 'a' is saved as a Character in the stack (rather than as a char), and then the conversion to Integer fails. You may need to first get the char out of the Character.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing a Char, not an Integer. You need to say something like this:

```
Char op1 = (Char)operands.peek();
int opcode = Char.digit(op1.charValue(),10);
```

(my Java is a bit rusty, so sorry if some of the method names are slightly wrong)

Also, is your **Peek** method returns null (becuase your **if** statement evaluated to false) then you code will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the char to an int

Easiest way is this:

```
operands.push(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(a)));
```